# How to rename the datasets used in a package?

Tags: r, package, devtools

I used `usethis::use_data(old_data)` after a long data preparation, but changed my mind and want my dataset named `NEW_DATA` instead, withut rerunning my data prep.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

We can load each file contained in the "data" folder, create a new variable with the new name in a new environment, remove the original file and save a new file.

The following function can be used:

```
#' rename package datasets
#'
#' Assuming `usethis::use_data()` was used, rename one or several datasets.
#'
#' @param ... One or more unquoted names, in the form `new_name = old_name`
rename_data <- function(...){
  args <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  env <- new.env()
  for(i in seq_along(args)){
    old_nm <- as.character(args[[i]])
    new_nm <- as.character(names(args)[[i]])
    old_path <- here::here("data", paste0(old_nm, ".rda"))
    new_path <- here::here("data", paste0(new_nm, ".rda"))
    load(old_path,env)
    assign(new_nm, eval(args[[i]],env), envir = env)
    file.remove(old_path)
    save(list=new_nm, file = new_path, envir = env)
  }
  invisible()
}

rename_data(NEW_DATA = old_data)
```